# Test to see if bean is instantiated?

Tags: xpages

I wanted to test to see if a session scope bean was in fact valid in a beforePageLoad event using SSJS. If I clear the session scopes using the Debug toolbar I get an error when trying to test the bean to see if it is null.

if (registrationBean == null){

The error is:
Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=2, col=22: [ReferenceError] 'registrationBean' not found

Question is how to test the bean to see if it is instantiated??? If not, then I want to go to another XPage (redirect) to allow the user to enter the values that are used to populate the bean.

Or, is this only an issue because I used the Debug Toolbar to clear ALL session and application scopes?

Howard

Answer (score 1):

Use a try/catch block. If you get the error, it's null.

I suspect it's only a problem because the applicationScope has been cleared. Usually the first attempt to reference the variable instantiates the object. However, clearing the whole of applicationScope can break a lot of XPages code in your application and should be avoided.

Comment: Yes, I think I am doing something that is not realistic. Even XPages with the debug toolbar on them (and just that) don't load! Good idea on the try/catch however. Shouldn't a bean be null if not instantiated?

Comment: The point is that if you try to check, the reference to the bean name will be passed to the VariableResolver. My understanding of what happens then is that the definition in the faces-config gives the mapping to the Java class. So if you reference the bean name, the XPages (JSF?) runtime identifies that you want it, so tries to find an existing instance of the variable in the relevant scope, otherwise lazy loads it. So basically, it can't be null unless the NSF's XPages runtime is screwed (as happened here, and you needed to rebuild it to solve).

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers another option is exception thrown in constructor

Comment: Would that occur? I thought beans had to have a blank constructor

Comment: Then yes, if the constructor has code without a try/catch block, that could be a cause.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am going to assume that clearing all the app scope and session scoped variables using debug toolbar was the issue. If I clear just my bean then the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that the bean is set up in faces_config.xml (but it seems this is the case). Then you should not be able to reference the bean before it is instantiated...

An easy way to see when the bean is instantiated is to put a System.out.println("....") in the constructor of the bean. That should bring you on the track. You could (should!) use the [OpenNTF LogReader](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/blog.xsp?permaLink=NHEF-8UXP49) to see what is going on - this will show you any errors thrown by the page and bean.

And then of course clearing all the data via the debug toolbar may put the system in an "unknown" state - and you should probably try to reload the page subsequently to ensure it is well-defined/-instantiated.

/John